# JOIN operation codeigniter shows empty results

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, join

I am pretty new to codeigniter and was trying a JOIN operation. my database table `users` structure is

```
id   username      password     user_type  cust_id
8     abc           xyz          cust        7
```

and `account_numbers` table is

```
bank_id     customer_id     ac_number  creation_date
3                    7          12345       2013-06-12
```

To get the account number for a known user id, i wrote

```
function get_ac_no($user_id)
{

    //echo $user_id;

    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('ac_number');
    $this->db->from('account_numbers');
    $this->db->join('users','account_numbers.customer_id = users.id');
    $this->db->where('customer_id ',$user_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $q = $this->db->get();

    $r = $q->result();

    var_dump( $r );
    return $r;       
}
```

But it shows empty results ! Can you suggest whats wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem in `users.id` so replace it with `users.cust_id` .
It may get the result you.
the correct code is :

```
function get_ac_no($user_id)
{

    //echo $user_id;

    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('ac_number');
    $this->db->from('account_numbers');
    $this->db->join('users','account_numbers.customer_id = users.cust_id');
    $this->db->where('account_numbers.customer_id ',$user_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $q = $this->db->get();

    $r = $q->result();

    var_dump( $r );
    return $r;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have no record to match user id and customer_id, so you can get null result set.
if your table record are like...

**users** table

```
 id   username      password     user_type  cust_id
 8     abc           xyz          cust        7
```

**account_numbers** table

```
bank_id     customer_id     ac_number  creation_date
3                    8          12345       2013-06-12
```

you can get one record..

use your join in above table your result like...

```
 ac_number
   12345
```

your join is match the **users** table **id** and **account_numbers** table **customer_id** ...

if you get record when match user id and costumer id.

sorry for my english .....